# How can I make the program to output the string which both two strings end on in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, string

I have two strings
e.g.

```
str1 = "Come"
str2 = "Rome"
```

I want the program to output ome.
How can I do that?

This is what I tried:

```
def getString(x): 
    return x

def solve(s1, s2): 

    a = getString(s1[0]) 
    b = getString(s2[0]) 

    for i in range(1, len(s1)): 
        if s1[i] != s1[i - 1]:  
            a += getString(s1[i]) 

    for i in range(1, len(s2)): 
        if s2[i] != s2[i - 1]: 
            b += getString(s2[i])      
    if a == b:
        print(a)
        return True
    return False
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I added it to the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: gave a wrong answer. This answer works but not the most efficent, although simple

```
for i in range(len(a)):
  if b.endswith(a[i:]):
    print(a[i:])
    return
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly.